При сборке билда в Unity ошибки: Starting a Gradle Daemon и Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, Gradle build failed
В логах 3 ошибки:
1 ошибка:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:extractReleaseAnnotations
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:createFullJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:appodeal.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:compressReleaseAssets

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar

> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\Users\Darkstar\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\044f513341ac9bd329d21343f6c6d1fa\transformed\jetified-interstitial-16.7.81-runtime.jar: D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.
WARNING:C:\U<message truncated>

2 ошибка:
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Note: G:\ProjectUnity\FPV_Drone\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-extractor:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-container:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-datasource:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-decoder:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-database:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-common:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 54s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

3 ошибка:
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
G:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "G:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-9P20JAN
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\Darkstar
OneDrive = C:\Users\Darkstar\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 3a09
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_8964_PNMZFNUNHTNVJDXN
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
JAVA_HOME = G:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = ZpUcbAdZXJYzNSoHsAWtL_s_JppwWid9
ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-9P20JAN
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 4
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
TMP = C:\Users\Darkstar\AppData\Local\Temp
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = UYDQtPOw83dIfVy3SrW5oMyo7ru4PRkV
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
TEMP = C:\Users\Darkstar\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;G:\IDE\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Darkstar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;G:\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin;;C:\Users\Darkstar\.dotnet\tools;G:\IDE\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Darkstar\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
USERNAME = Darkstar
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-9P20JAN
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemDrive = C:
windir = C:\WINDOWS
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = jTIgKs5KTZOjiqEEVdZFbgo_VRhABduL
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\Darkstar\AppData\Roaming
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
SESSIONNAME = Console
PyCharm Community Edition = G:\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin;
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\Darkstar\AppData\Local
HOMEPATH = \Users\Darkstar
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
HOMEDRIVE = C:
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-9P20JAN
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Note: G:\ProjectUnity\FPV_Drone\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-extractor:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-container:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-datasource:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-decoder:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-database:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-common:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'
     
     Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 54s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties



Последний лог целиком не влез, залил на гитхаб логи: https://github.com/GamestudioVFN/FailedBuild

Ответ же на виду: Dependency 'androidx.media3:XXX:1.2.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 34 or higher. Compilation target for module ':launcher' is 'android-33'. Используемая вами библиотека androidx.media3 требует SDK 34. Ваш же проект все еще на SDK 33.

Либо понижайте версию библиотеки, либо повышайте SDK проекта.
